# Why would the adjunct be able to arrest Whiskeyjack openly?

Tags: malazan

On page 668 of my copy of Gardens of the Moon, when the Adjunct is stalking the Coin Bearer and thinking about the Tyrant's death, she (somehow?) infers that Whiskeyjack is still alive (not sure how she does this), but that once the Empress and Tayschrenn take over Darujhistan they could make Whiskeyjack's arrest "a public spectacle".

It then goes onto say "With this coup even Dujek could not challenge them". What coup is she talking about? I don't think she yet knows explicitly what Dujek and Whiskeyjack are planning, and she also Whiskeyjack seemed to be following her orders as well. So why does she think her, the Empress and Tayschrenn would have had "probable cause"- so to speak- to reprimand him?

Comment: I think the "coup" is successfully taking Darujhistan, which would be a great PR win for the Empress.